# Flutter webRTC | How do I end the call when the user receives another call and has picked that call up

Tags: android, flutter, webrtc

When `User1` is voice calling `User2` through my webRTC app... And `User1` receives a call not from my app  but from any other app *(Whatsapp , Messenger)* and `User1` decides to pick that call.. After picking that call, **How do I tell my webRTC app that `User1` has picked a call from outside the app so end the call with `User2`**

**========================================================**

Basically I would like to listen the call state of the phone...

**Notify my app that I'm receiving a Call.**

**Notify my app that I have picked up a Call.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_state

You could listen to underlining event

```
_watchAllRawEvents() {
  FlutterPhoneState.rawPhoneEvent.forEach((RawPhoneEvent event) {
    final phoneCall = event.call;
    print("Got an event $event");
  });
  print("That loop ^^ won't end");
}
```